# How does one take an MPEG4/MP3 AVI and re-encapsulate it in MP4?

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, mp3, video-conversion, avi

I've been trying to take an old AVI file I have that has an MPEG4 video with MP3 audio and re-encapsulate it in an MP4 container. The audio was easy enough to figure out (`-acodec libfaac`), but I don't want to re-encode the video. I've had a number of issues when I've tried with `ffmpeg` but kept getting errors like `[mp4 @ 0x7fe6cc01f200] pts has no value` and severe stutter in the resulting videos.

So what I'd like to know is what can I use to re-encapsulate an MPEG4 stream in an AVI file into an MP4 file (preferably on Mac OS X)?

Comment: Please include the full uncut ffmpeg command line output. Also, why do you need it in a different container if the existing one works?

Comment: @slhck Lots of non replies lately...